# exported fbx with multiple textures has only one

Tags: texturing, materials, export, import, unity

I created an object with multiple textures. It looks fine in "Viewport-Shading - Texture". When it's in "Material" mode it fully has only the first texture. It also happens when rendering. When I export it as fbx and import it to unity it also has only that oe texture. Why can it happen?

Answer (score -1):

You have to assign every material to its part and not only unwrap it with the textures.